# How to create JOBDIR settings in Scrpay Spider dynamically?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-settings

I want to create `JOBDIR` setting from Spider `__init__` or dynamically when I call that spider .
I want to create  different `JOBDIR` for different spiders , like `FEED_URI` in the below example

```
    class QtsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'qts'
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI': 'data_files/' + '%(site_name)s.csv',
        'FEED_FORMAT': "csv",
        #'JOBDIR': 'resume/' + '%(site_name2)s'
    }
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com']


    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(QtsSpider, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.site_name = kw.get('site_name')

    def parse(self, response):
        #our rest part of code
```

and we are calling that script from this way

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


def main_function():
    all_spiders = ['spider1','spider2','spider3'] # 3 different spiders
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    for spider_name in all_spiders:
        process.crawl('qts', site_name = spider_name )

    process.start()

main_function()
```

How to achieve that dynamic creation of `JOBDIR` for different Spider like `FEED_URI` ?? Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself needing the same sort of functionality, mostly due to not wanting to repetitively add a custom `JOBDIR` to each spider's `custom_settings` property. So, I created a simple `extension` that subclasses the original `SpiderState` extension that Scrapy utilizes to save the state of crawls.

```py
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured
from scrapy.extensions.spiderstate import SpiderState
import os


class SpiderStateManager(SpiderState):
    """
    SpiderState Purpose: Store and load spider state during a scraping job
    Added Purpose: Create a unique subdirectory within JOBDIR for each spider based on spider.name property
    Reasoning: Reduces repetitive code
    Usage: Instead of needing to add subdirectory paths in each spider.custom_settings dict
        Simply specify the base JOBDIR in settings.py and the subdirectories are automatically managed
    """

    def __init__(self, jobdir=None):
        self.jobdir = jobdir
        super(SpiderStateManager, self).__init__(jobdir=self.jobdir)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        base_jobdir = crawler.settings['JOBDIR']
        if not base_jobdir:
            raise NotConfigured
        spider_jobdir = os.path.join(base_jobdir, crawler.spidercls.name)
        if not os.path.exists(spider_jobdir):
            os.makedirs(spider_jobdir)

        obj = cls(spider_jobdir)
        crawler.signals.connect(obj.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler.signals.connect(obj.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return obj
```

To enable it, remember to add the proper settings to your `settings.py` like so

```py
EXTENSIONS = {
    # We want to disable the original SpiderState extension and use our own
    "scrapy.extensions.spiderstate.SpiderState": None,
    "spins.extensions.SpiderStateManager": 0
}
JOBDIR = "C:/Users/CaffeinatedMike/PycharmProjects/ScrapyDapyDoo/jobs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how you have set the site_name, you can pass another argument,

```
process.crawl('qts', site_name=spider_name, jobdir='dirname that you want to keep')
```

will be available as a spiders attribute so you can write

```
def __init__(self):
    jobdir = getattr(self, 'jobdir', None)    

    if jobdir:
        self.custom_settings['JOBDIR'] = jobdir
```

Comment: custom_settings are a crawler setting, not a spider settng, you can't pass them in the class init, they are ignored